# Cannot update database because entity cannot drop constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created some new tables and I noticed I didn't use the good naming convention for the ids.

So I did a new `add-migration` with the new ids but when I try to `update-database` I have the following error :

> The constraint 'PK_dbo.DB_User_Type' is being referenced by table
>   'AspNetUsers', foreign key constraint
>   'FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.DB_User_Type_DB_User_Type_Id'. Could not drop
>   constraint. See previous errors.

I don't understand because the script starts by dropping all constraints.

Could someone explain how to solve this error please?

I'm using the new approach `code first from an existing database` from entity 6.1. Here is the `Up` function

```
public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", "DB_Category_Id", "dbo.DB_Category");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", "DB_Category_Id", "dbo.DB_Category");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", "DB_User_Type_Id", "dbo.DB_User_Type");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", "category_id", "dbo.DB_Category");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", "category_id", "dbo.DB_Category");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "DB_User_Type_user_type_id", "dbo.DB_User_Type");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", "user_type_id", "dbo.DB_User_Type");
            DropIndex("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", new[] { "DB_Category_Id" });
            DropIndex("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", new[] { "DB_Category_Id" });
            DropIndex("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", new[] { "DB_User_Type_Id" });
            DropColumn("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", "category_id");
            DropColumn("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", "category_id");
            DropColumn("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", "user_type_id");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.AspNetUsers", name: "DB_User_Type_Id", newName: "DB_User_Type_user_type_id");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DB_Company_Profile", name: "DB_Category_Id", newName: "category_id");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DB_Category_Translation", name: "DB_Category_Id", newName: "category_id");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", name: "DB_User_Type_Id", newName: "user_type_id");
            RenameIndex(table: "dbo.AspNetUsers", name: "IX_DB_User_Type_Id", newName: "IX_DB_User_Type_user_type_id");
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DB_Category");
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DB_User_Type");
            AddColumn("dbo.DB_Category", "category_id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddColumn("dbo.DB_User_Type", "user_type_id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AlterColumn("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", "category_id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", "category_id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", "user_type_id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DB_Category", "category_id");
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DB_User_Type", "user_type_id");
            CreateIndex("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", "category_id");
            CreateIndex("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", "category_id");
            CreateIndex("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", "user_type_id");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.DB_Company_Profile", "category_id", "dbo.DB_Category", "category_id", cascadeDelete: true);
            AddForeignKey("dbo.DB_Category_Translation", "category_id", "dbo.DB_Category", "category_id", cascadeDelete: true);
            AddForeignKey("dbo.DB_User_Type_Translation", "user_type_id", "dbo.DB_User_Type", "user_type_id", cascadeDelete: true);
            AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "DB_User_Type_user_type_id", "dbo.DB_User_Type", "user_type_id");
            DropColumn("dbo.DB_Category", "Id");
            DropColumn("dbo.DB_User_Type", "Id");
        }
```

Comment: if u dont have data, cleanest way is to delete the DB>

Comment: Then it says it doesn't exist. I guess I have to do something else than update-database

Comment: I guess I could target another migration but I would like to know if there's something less complicated

Comment: @DarthVader do you know if there's another way than modifying the database and make a new model?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. [This post helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34549700/2961887)

The problem is that EF didn't automatically renamed my `FK_CONSTRAINST`. As a result the `DropForeignKey()` wasn't correct. You can solve this by manual SQL queries (check post above). But I solved it by first changing the `FK_CONSTRAINST` manually in the DB. Remember you can use `-Verbose` to check the queries. It's easier debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I had to delete the foreign key manually before running the `update-database` command. Because the constraint name in my DB is something like: `FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.DB_User_Type_DB_User_TypeId`

While the constraint the script is trying to drop is: 
`FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.DB_User_Type_DB_User_Type_Id`

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some rules about foreign keys - some of them are meant to handle situations, when you try to delete a record that has another records associated with it. 
In your case, it seems like you want to apply the `CASCADE` rule to your relationships. This way entity will delete all its FKs

Comment: Is it normal that I have this error then if there's no data?

Comment: Could you provide an example with entity?

Comment: In order to do the CASCADE, you need to modify the table that establish PK-FK relationships. You need to modify the constraint itself.

Answer (score -1):

1. `DropForeignKey("dependantTable", "dependantColumn", "principalTable")`
2. `DropPrimaryKey("principalTable")`
3. `AddPrimaryKey("principalTable", "principalColumn",)`
4. `AddForeignKey("dependantTable", "dependantColumn", "principalTable")`