# Entity Framework Migrations can't drop table because of foreign key constraint

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have reverse-engineered the existing database to the code-first model. Some tables are to be kept but most are to be removed and completely re-architected for the new version.

I delete some old classes and their mapping and add-migration.

The migration looks like this:

```
  public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Review", "BingoID", "dbo.Bingo");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Review_Text", "BingoReviewID", "dbo.Bingo_Review");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Bonus", "BingoID", "dbo.Bingo");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount", "BingoBonusID", "dbo.Bingo_Bonus");
            DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Bonus", new[] { "BingoID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Review", new[] { "BingoID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Review_Text", new[] { "BingoReviewID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount", new[] { "BingoBonusID" });
            DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus");
            DropTable("dbo.Bingo");
            DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Review");
            DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Review_Text");
            DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount");
            DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Type");
        }
```

However when I run the migration, I get the following error in package manager console.

```
Could not drop object 'dbo.Bingo_Bonus' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

Why do I get this error when the migration should have already dropped any foreign keys prior to the drop table command? Is there any way around this?

Comment: May be you still forgot to remove BingoBonusID from any table. Once check it may be u will got solution.

Comment: Thanks. However I searched the solution for bingo and the only reference to it is in the migration class I provided above.

Answer (score 44):

If the `dbo.Bingo_Bonus` table name has ever changed, or if any of the columns in the foreign key relationships have changed, EF does not rename the foreign key constraints automatically to match.  I had a similar problem and I had to manually add a line like this because the `DropForeignKey()` function was not actually deleting the key it was supposed to:

```
Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Constraint_Name_From_Before_Table_Change]");
```

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't know that EF does not rename foreign key constraints. I solved a similar problem by first changing the FK Constraint manually.

Comment: Same but little bit nicer: DropForeignKey("dbo.MyTable","FK_dbo.Constraint_Name_From_Before_Table_Change");

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I was beyond confused why my drop foreign key command seemed to have no effect (I renamed it at one point)

Comment: @akl22 Thank you sooo much. This really saved me. During Development, I changed the Name of the table. But not anymore. Note to myself: Never change Tablename AGAIN. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot drop `Bingo_Bonus` table, because it still has references to `Bingo_Bonus_Amount` and `Bingo_Bonus_Type` tables, changing the order in the Up() method will solve the problem

by putting :

```
DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount");
DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Type");
```

before:

```
DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus");
```

Your code will be:

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Review", "BingoID", "dbo.Bingo");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Review_Text", "BingoReviewID", "dbo.Bingo_Review");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Bonus", "BingoID", "dbo.Bingo");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount", "BingoBonusID", "dbo.Bingo_Bonus");
        DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Bonus", new[] { "BingoID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Review", new[] { "BingoID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Review_Text", new[] { "BingoReviewID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount", new[] { "BingoBonusID" });
        DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Amount");
        DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus_Type");
        DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Bonus");
        DropTable("dbo.Bingo");
        DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Review");
        DropTable("dbo.Bingo_Review_Text");

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `DropForeignKey()` override that takes the name of the Foreign Key.

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.BingoReview","dbo.FK_Constraint_Name");
```

And like the other responses mention, if the table has been changed, you can use the original name.

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.BingoReview","dbo.FK_Constraint_Name_From_Before_Table_Change");
```

Thanks @akl22 for providing this in a comment.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. It is a nicer solution than injecting sql into your Up / Down migrations

Comment: A complete solution should mention the full syntax for adding back the foreign key. In the Down() method, you need to specify the old FK constraint name: AddForeignKey("dbo.BingoReview", "ForeignKeyField", "ForeignTable", "ForeignPKField", false, "dbo.FK_Constraint_name_from_Before_Table_Change");. The false is to prevent cascade delete, which is the default value when not specified.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to drop using GUI.   When tried to run the query with alter , the '.' symbol was having some error displayed

[image]
[image]
[image]