# Unable to delete FK from model code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a created an MVC application using the code-first approach with an existing database.

I have noticed that one of my tables doesn't need a foreign key, so I have tried to delete it but I keep getting:

> The object 'FK_BorrowedProperty_codeStatus' is dependent on column 'StatusId'.
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN StatusId failed because one or more objects access this column.

**Steps I have done**

- Gone into `BorrowedProperty` class and deleted `public int StatusId { get; set; }` & `public virtual codeStatu codeStatu { get; set; }`
- Went into `CodeStatu` class and deleted `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
      public virtual ICollection<BorrowedProperty> BorrowedProperties { get; set; }`
- Gone into my DbContext and commented out this line `//modelBuilder.Entity<codeStatu>()
          //    .HasMany(e => e.BorrowedProperties)
          //    .WithRequired(e => e.codeStatu)
          //    .HasForeignKey(e => e.StatusId)
          //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`
- Add-Migration DeleteStatusFKFromBorrowedProperty

That results in:

```
public partial class DeleteStatusFKFromBorrowedProperty : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId", "dbo.codeStatus");
        DropIndex("dbo.BorrowedProperty", new[] { "StatusId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId", "dbo.codeStatus", "Id");
    }
}
```

- update-database

Then I receive the error above.  There are **zero** records in the BorrowedProperty database table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From exception message it is clear that you've foreign key constraint named `FK_BorrowedProperty_codeStatus` which prevents `StatusId` column to be dropped. You can create a method which contains SQL command to remove FK constraint like this:

```
private void DropForeignKeyConstraint()
{
    // This command may work if the constraint name is known:
    // Sql(@"ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BorrowedProperty] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_BorrowedProperty_codeStatus]");

    Sql(@"DECLARE @constraint NVARCHAR(128)
        SELECT @constraint = name
        FROM sys.default_constraints
        WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'dbo.BorrowedProperty')
        AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'StatusId';
        IF @constraint IS NOT NULL
           EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BorrowedProperty] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @constraint + ']')");
}
```

Put the method inside `Up` method on migration code like this:

```
public partial class DeleteStatusFKFromBorrowedProperty : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKeyConstraint(); // dropping FK constraint first
        DropForeignKey("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId", "dbo.codeStatus");
        DropIndex("dbo.BorrowedProperty", new[] { "StatusId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.BorrowedProperty", "StatusId"); // drop column at last
    }
}
```

Or if you've access to SSMS instance, run this query directly:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BorrowedProperty] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_BorrowedProperty_codeStatus]
```

NB: You can try commenting out all code lines in `Down` method to see if foreign key constraint doesn't recreated.

Afterwards, you can perform `Add-Migration` & `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console to apply changes above.

Similar issues:

[The object 'DF__*' is dependent on column '*' - Changing int to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460912/the-object-df-is-dependent-on-column-changing-int-to-double)

[How do I drop a column with object dependencies in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253185/how-do-i-drop-a-column-with-object-dependencies-in-sql-server-2008)

[Entity Framework Migrations can't drop table because of foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500784/entity-framework-migrations-cant-drop-table-because-of-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Okay I do have access to SSMS instance, of which I used, but I was wondering about the method solution.. do I have to create that in a specific area (like in the migration.cs) or can I put it anywhere and just reference it in the migration.cs?

Comment: I used the query directly: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BorrowedProperty] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_BorrowedProperty_codeStatus] and worked perfectly